# SELECT UNION query with random rows from multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I have different tables : A,B,C ... 
And I want to select a number given of rows from each table and make an union

I used this query (number given = 100) :

```
sql_query = ''' SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100 
             UNION SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100 '''
```

but when I try to read the DataFrame :

```
df=pd.read_sql(sql_query, con)
```

I have an error :

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql : LIMIT clause should come after UNION not before
```

If I use the LIMIT clause after UNION, it would return only the number given of rows but I don't know how many rows from each table were extracted.

Example : if I want 100 rows from A and 100 rows from B, using the LIMIT 200 Clause after the UNION, I will have 200 rows but I don't know how many rows were extracted from A and from B

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using derived tables (subqueries in `FROM` clause) to set the `LIMIT`. You likely also want `UNION ALL` to keep duplicates, otherwise you may receive less than 100 records per table.

```
sql_query = ''' SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100)'''
```

Alternatively, read each table iteratively and concatenate to a final dataframe:

```
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM {} ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100'

df_list = [pd.read_sql(sql_query.format(t), con) for t in ['A', 'B']]

df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I wanted to avoid concatenating dataframes

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from SQLite.

Try the following SQL using the `WITH` clause, or [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
sql_query = """
WITH 
  aa AS (SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5),
  bb AS (SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5)
SELECT * FROM aa UNION SELECT * FROM bb;
"""
```